# Prove that cardinality of linearly independent set is less than or equal to spanning set

Tags: linear-algebra

My professor did this proof in class and I was not able to copy down the proof. I managed to get half of it but I don't quite understand how to continue.

He essentially took a basis and kept adding vectors from a linearly independent set and removing one from that set. I don't know what to do next. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you talking about finite-dimensional vector spaces? I believe that the proof is very different if you don't require that the vector space be finite-dimensional.

Comment: Can you post the part of the proof that you did manage to copy down, so that we can see where you are stuck?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your professor actually proved *Steinitz' exchange lemma*, or something very close to this lemma, which I'll quote:

> Suppose $v_1,\dots, v_m$ be a set of linearly independent vectors and $S=\{w_1,\dots, w_n\}$ a spanning set of a vector space $V$. Then:
>
> 1. $m\le n$;
> 2. There exists a reordering of $S$ such that the set $\{v_1,\dots,v_m,v_{m+1},\dots,v_n\}$  spans $V$.

In other words, up to a reordering of $S$, we can replace the first $m$ vectors in the spanning set with the vectors in the linearly independent set.

The proof consists in proving by induction that for all $k\;(0\le k\le m)$, up to a reordering of $S$, the set
$$\{v_1,\dots,v_k,w_{k+1},\dots,w_m\}$$
is a spanning set for $V$.

*A hint for the inductive step*: if the assertion is proved for a given $k$, the vector $v_{k+1}$ can be written as
$$v_{k+1}=\sum_{i=1}^k \lambda_iv_i+\sum_{i=k+1}^n\lambda_iw_i.$$
Observe that, since the first set is linearly independent, at least $1$ $\lambda_i,\;i\ge k+1$ is non zero. Up to a reordering of $S$, we may suppose it is $\lambda_{k+1}$,and so you can check that $w_{k+1}$ is in the span of
$\{v_1,\dots, v_{k+1},w_{k+2},\dots,w_n\}$.